Where to download Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I'm looking for the official website to download Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Noble Numbat.
Where can I find it? Currently there is only Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I'm still running a QA test on an ISO that was only generated an little over an hour ago... If you want a stable system, please wait for it to be deemed ready..   A quick look at the ISO QA tracker can show what parts are marked Ready and what isn't.. Release occurs when it's all ready.

Just be patient.
The Release Team has a lot of work to squeeze into one day (see the checklist and the tracking). It's more complex than push-one-button.
So releases have never been at the stroke of midnight.
The release will occur when it's ready.
Just be patient.
